# Behavoirs в yii для AR-моделей

Tags: yii

Почитал про behavoirs в yii и возник вопрос. Если для обновления и вставки записи в таблицу используется один метод save(), можно ли написать behavoir именно к обновлению, а не к добавлению записи? Или никак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение в behavoir beforeSave проверять isNewRecord. Если false, произошло обновление. Если имеется более элегантное решение, предлагайте.

Comment: Все правильно. Элегантнее уже некуда. Можете засчитать себе ответ :)

Comment: @VasyOk, репутация не позволяет)

Answer (score -1):

ну вообщето если посмотреть на код метода save

```
public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null) 
{ 
    if(!$runValidation || $this->validate($attributes)) 
        return $this->getIsNewRecord() ? $this->insert($attributes) : $this->update($attributes); 
    else 
        return false; 
}
```

то по сути выполняется метод insert или update, то и ставь на них поведения

Comment: @Ale_x, я смотрел. Но переписывать уже имеющийся код на insert'ы и update'ы уже не вариант. Везде использовалось save(). А afterUpdate() нет такого((